# nestjs configuration with dotenv

Tags: configuration, nestjs

Referring to [official NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration), it is recommended to use `ConfigService` in order to use environment variables.

So in the code, we access all vars defined in an `.env` file with something like:

```
config.get('PORT')
```

But it is not recommended to use `.env` in production environment. So how to deploy in that way?

Why not just use the standard method with `dotenv` and `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: It's not recommended to _commit_ the .env file, not to _use_ It. Basically your env file will hold your secrets, so passwords for example will be not committed in your VCS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems that make the `ConfigService` less useful.

**First**

When no `.env` file is present in any environment, `readFileSync` in

```
dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath))
```

will fail:

```
[Nest] 63403 [ExceptionHandler] path must be a string or Buffer
TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at new ConfigService (../config/config.service.ts:8:38)
```

Even if e.g. `process.env.API_KEY` is available

```
this.configService.get('API_KEY')
```

will not return anything. So the `ConfigService` forces you to use a `prod.env` file, which dotenv advocates against:

> No. We strongly recommend against having a "main" .env file and an
>   "environment" .env file like .env.test. Your config should vary
>   between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between
>   environments.

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files

**Second**

You have to import the config module and inject the service in order to use it. When you use env variables like this

```
imports: [
  MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }),
  ConfigModule,
],
```

the config service is useless.

Read more about config in the environment here: https://12factor.net/config

Comment: i have just been coming to this realization, how does nest expect us to use config service in a real production environment? 
i.e. say env is injected via docker, bash etc ?

Comment: if anyone cares, i've just added   
    `if (process.env[key]) {
      return process.env[key];
    }
 return this.envConfig[key];
`
...to my config.service.ts, which surprisingly, seems to work fine just like that

Comment: somehow the nestjs build, does not copy the .env files to the dist folder and as a result I keep getting file not found error

Answer (score 4):

> But this is not recommended to use .env in production environnement. So how to deploy that way ?

Actually, it is not recommended **to commit** your .env files. It's perfectly fine to use them in production :-).

> Why not use the standard method with dotenv and process.env.PORT?

It allows **decoupling** your core code from the code responsible for providing configuration data. Thus:

- The core code is easier to test: doing some manual changes/mocking of `process.env` is **such** - **a** - **pain**, whereas mocking a "`ConfigService`" is pretty easy
- You can imagine using anything else than environment variables in the future by just replacing a single method (or a few getters) in a dedicated class, instead of replacing all the occurrences of `process.env.*` in your code // *to be fair, this is unlikely to happen, as using env. variables is the most common way to load configuration data, but still.*

Answer (score 0):

Using `@nestjs/config` (a.k.a. `ConfigModule`) makes environment variables available to your app whether they come from a `.env` file or set in the environment. Locally you use a `.env` file and on production use the environment.